# Accessing file from a file server

Tags: file, nio, java-11

I want a fetch a pdf file from a specific path of a file server which is placed outside of my web application . Currently I'm doing it by reading the file using file inputstream and writing the same in specific path inside of my application then only I can access that file is there in new way in java 8 or 11 so that I can avoid that write operation inside of my application

Comment: What does “reading the file using file inputstream” mean?

Comment: What you are doing with that temporary copy of the PDF file? If your code e.g. uses it for sending the file to a web client that you could directly use the InputStream to read and send the data. But that depends on your used web framework and what you are doing with that PDF file.